# Can't use certain functions in OpenGL (glGenBuffers)

Tags: opengl, glew, glfw

I have seen similar questions to mine else where but none have answered or fixed my problem.

I have *GLEW* initiated properly, right after the *Context* creation but before I call `glfwMakeContextCurrent()`

After I have initiated I try to use `glGenBuffers()` but it doesn't work. Throws an error.

My OpenGL version is 3.2 so from what I have read I can use this functionality in my program. Please to let me know otherwise though if I can't. I will try to figure out a different way to do this.

I am using *Windows 7* and *VS2012*, and it seems that everything is linked properly. Hope I provided all the info I needed.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <stdio.h>

#include <GL/glew.h>

#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <thread>

int main(){

//Initialize GLFW
if(!glfwInit()){
    printf("GLFW was not initialized successfully!\n");
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
else{
    printf("GLFW was initialized successfully!\n");
}

glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "PONG!", nullptr, nullptr); // Windowed

glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
if(!glewInit()){
    printf("GLEW was not initialized successfully!\n");
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
else{
    printf("GLEW was initialized successfully!\n");
}

glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

GLuint vertexbuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);

printf("%u\n", vertexbuffer);

fprintf(
    stdout,
    "INFO: The OpenGL version is: %s\n",
    glGetString(GL_VERSION)
);

fprintf(
    stdout,
    "INFO: The GLEW version is: %s\n",
    glewGetString(GLEW_VERSION)
);

while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();

    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS){
        glfwDestroyWindow(window);
        window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "PONG!", nullptr, nullptr);
    }
    else if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_F) == GLFW_PRESS){
        glfwDestroyWindow(window);
        window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "PONG!", glfwGetPrimaryMonitor(), nullptr);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: "Throws an error."  Are you going to tell us what the error message is?

Comment: Access Violation. That is all it says.

Comment: That's already quite helpful.  Run in debug mode and tell us what line it is pointing to when it faults (and if not in your code, what the call stack is)

Comment: Then your context isn't in a proper shape and/or the function isn't loaded properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have *GLEW* initiated properly, right after the *Context* creation but before I call `glfwMakeContextCurrent()`

Welp, there's your problem [right there](http://www.glfw.org/docs/3.0/group__window.html#ga5c336fddf2cbb5b92f65f10fb6043344):

> Successful creation **does not change which context is current**. Before you can use the newly created context, you need to make it current using `glfwMakeContextCurrent`.

Call `glewInit()` *after* `glfwMakeContextCurrent()`.

Comment: Okay I did do that. And I still get the same error. Could I be ordering something else wrong?

Comment: @Wesley you accepted this as the response after saying it didn't solve your problem. So what was the solution? This site isn't just about helping yourself, you know! It's supposed to be a knowledge base.